# Proving identity of electromagnetism in GR

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, general-relativity

I am trying to prove the following identity from Geroch's lecture notes on GR:

$$
F_{am}\xi^m=F_{mn}\xi^mh^n_a
$$

Where

$$
h_{ab}=g_{ab}+\xi_a\xi_b
$$

Is the projection operator orthogonal to $\xi_a$, $\xi_a$ is a time-like unit 4-velocity vector and $F_{ab}$ is the electromagnetic tensor.

I, however, reached a different result:

$$F_{mn}\xi^mh^n_a=F_{mn}\xi^m(\delta^n_a+\xi_a\xi^n)=F_{ma}\xi^m+F_{ma}\xi^m\xi_a\xi^a=F_{ma}\xi^m-F_{ma}\xi^m$$

Which is obviously zero, but since $F_{ab}$ is anti-symmetric we have $-F_{ma}=F_{am}$.

Also, using that $F_{(ab)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(F_{ab}+F_{ba}\right)$, I arrived in:

$$
\boxed{F_{mn}\xi^mh^n_a=2F_{(am)}\xi^m}
$$

Obviously something is wrong, but I cannot figure out what. Anny help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In your first expression, you've messed up indices.  That second term should be $F_{mn}\xi^{m}\xi_{a}\xi^{n}$, which is zero, and your result follows.

Comment: I see. I was confused on what to do with the $n$ index on the second term, because on the first (due to the $\delta$) we set $n=a$ so I thought everywhere else in the expression $n$ should be replaced by $a$. But I suppose my reasoning was wrong then?

Also, could you clarify a bit on $F_{mn}\xi^m\xi_a\xi^n=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an index error in your first term.

You have:

$$\begin{align}
F_{ab}h_{m}{}^{a}\xi^{b} &= F_{ab}\xi^{b}\left(\delta_{m}{}^{a} + \xi_{m}\xi^{a}\right) \\
 &= F_{mb}\xi^{b} + F_{ab}\xi^{a}\xi^{b}\xi_{m}
\end{align}$$

However, we obviously have $\xi^{a}\xi^{b} = \xi^{b}\xi^{a}$

This means

$$\begin{align}
F_{ab}\xi^{a}\xi^{b} &= - F_{ba}\xi^{a}\xi^{b}\\
&= - F_{ba}\xi^{b}\xi^{a}
\end{align}$$

This means that this contraction is equal to minus itself, and therefore must be zero (as is true for any symmetric matrix multiplied by any antisymmetric matrix).  This means the second term is zero, and we get your desired result:

$$F_{ab}h_{m}{}^{a}\xi^{b} = F_{mb}\xi^{b}$$

This is, of course, a natural result.  Assume that $\xi^{a} = \partial_{t}$ in some $(t,x,y,z)$ coordinate system.  Then, $F_{ta} = F_{ba}\xi^{b}$, but the antisymmetry of $F_{ab}$ tells us that if a = t, then $F_{ta}= 0$, and the values of $F_{ta}$ are unaffected for $a \neq t$, so the projection operator onto the 3-space is nilpotent for these coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this. It is clear to me now where I got it wrong.